# What image similarity measure is best for measuring the structural similarity of two images?

Tags: python, computer-vision, image-processing

I am looking for an image similarity measure that can measure the differences between the structural composition of two images. For example these two images have structural differences between them

[image]

[image]

So I am looking for an image similarity measure that can identify that structural difference, the structural similarity of two images basically.

One of the methods I found was SSIM, but it measures the structural, luminance, and contrast of the images, and I don't want to take into account the luminance difference or contrast difference, just the structural similarity.

Comment: I don't think you're representing SSIM correctly: It takes contrast and luminance *into account* to be able to *compensate* for them. You can fiddle with the composition of these errors in the final SSIM index to your liking, and if you find one is actually irrelevant to your problem, just not include it at all. So, what's actually wrong with [SSIM](http://www.cns.nyu.edu/pub/eero/wang03-reprint.pdf)?

Comment: Ahh I actually didn't fully understand your comment Marcus. I've never used SSIM before just read about it in this article - https://medium.com/srm-mic/all-about-structural-similarity-index-ssim-theory-code-in-pytorch-6551b455541e. What do you mean by things like into account, composition of errors, and not including an aspect?

Comment: Please see the paper I linked to. For a quick dive, see Fig. 3, which your medium post cites so much, you could have read the original source in the first place! It really illustrates how it *uses* the luminance and contrast to make the structure representation robust.

Comment: Do you mean structure similarity by understand both images are of the same building?